# "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" when importing into App.js for React App created using CDN links

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, babeljs

I have created a React App that renders and h1 tag with "Hello World" to the browser. I have setup the App using CDN links rather than npm. The App has three files:

1. index.html with one div tag with id of "root"
2. App.js which renders my jsx to the div tag called root
3. styles.css which I intent to use for some styles

Now the challenge is when I add `import './styles.css'` at the top of my App.js, the App breaks and nothing appears on the browser. Upon inspecting the browser console I find the error message:

"App.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"-
[Here is the screenshot of the error message from the browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyiNA.png)

My question is how do I import scripts/ other react components into my App.js without getting this error message? Why is babel giving me this error?

Here are the index.html, style.css and App.js codes:

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
    <div>
      <h1 className="heading">Hello World</h1>
    </div>)
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
.heading{
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: blueviolet;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="style.css">
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/react@16.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js'></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
   
    <script src="App.js" type="text/babel">

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-import-css (I have absolutely no idea if that can be persuaded to run client side)

Comment: I think the main problem is the setting on babel for import and exporting, try create-react-app bundle for the project

Comment: @RezaDwiputra I would have used the create-react-app but the nature of the project/ assignment requires me to use CDN links.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out that the easiest solution is to link into my index.html like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```